# Another PHP JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, jsonexception

So i am trying to create a registersite on my android app. I have been following Toni Kami step by step guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M&index=1&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka

Atm Im at a complete halt and up to hours trying to fix a json exception that im having and i now desperately turn to your fine people for help.

the error goes like this:
[image]

RegisterActivity.java = http://pastebin.com/0zy3UZYc

RegisterRequest.java = http://pastebin.com/RZXfHcmn

register.php =  http://pastebin.com/pAuAGnTt

I read around that in most cases it is the URL thats the problem but when i paste the url in chrome then it does echo connected.

this is the return string: 
I/tagconvertstr: [
                                                                           **Notice**:  Undefined variable: con in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Yield\PhpFiles\register.php** on line **12**
                                                                           
                                                                           **Warning**:  mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Yield\PhpFiles\register.php** on line **12**
                                                                           
                                                                           **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Yield\PhpFiles\register.php** on line **13**
                                                                           
                                                                           **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Yield\PhpFiles\register.php** on line **14**

the lines it is complaining about are these:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
                                                                       ]
```

I really hope someone can enlighten me here and feel free to ask for mere information.

Thx!

Comment: `echo ("connected");` <-- that will make the response invalid JSON.

Comment: I know but it is not the echos. I have tried removing them

Comment: According to your error screenshot, it is. If you've removed the echos, then you should see a different error message, what is it.

Comment: Just updated the screenshot. sorry about that

Comment: Okay, so now it seems that you're outputting a `br` HTML tag somewhere before the json_encode.

Comment: Go directly to the URL that your app is calling in your browser. View source, and show us what it says.

Comment: just updated the question again with the url info

Comment: Please post the response json (get the source of the echoed page)

Comment: well i guess the error is nothing is being posted since im not posting anything from browser. I guess the same is happening onclick event in the app what i dont know is why?

Comment: Bah, I didn't consider this is a POST request with my last comment... So ignoring that, you should be able to view the full response string in your IDE.

Comment: Can you help me through how to view full return string in android studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because there is a mix of mysql_ and mysqli_

if you make everything mysqli_

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","", "yield");


    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") or die (mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

then it works!

Answer (score 1):

use

Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");
to view the returned response

before line
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

in RegisterActivity.java